# ARM MOV move between register and stack pointer

Tags: arm64

The description for the Stack Move (MOV) indicates it can go from register to stack register and vice versa but it only has one register variable.  How does it know which way to go?  If not which way does it go?

Here it is in the manual:
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2020-12/Base-Instructions/MOV--to-from-SP---Move-between-register-and-stack-pointer--an-alias-of-ADD--immediate--?lang=en

Comment: What do you mean by "only one register variable"?  It works the same as regular `MOV`.  Namely `MOV SP, X0` to move to the stack pointer, and `MOV X0, SP` to move from it.

Comment: It's listed in the manual that Rd and Rn should be the same so that only leaves you with one register? I think MOV SP,X0 is the register version that lets you copy from register to register.  My question is what happens when you only list one register?  Does it copy to or from the stack?

Comment: "It's listed in the manual that Rd and Rn should be the same" - no it isn't?

Comment: I posted a picture that shows that the SP MOV has one register 1'd out.  It makes sense that you only specify one register to move to the stack.  But I'm assuming it's one-way.

Comment: I think you're misreading something, but I can't quite tell what.  Are you looking at the `Rd = Rn` line at the top?  That's a description of the instruction's operation, not its encoding: it sets register Rd to the value from register Rn.

Comment: But as it says, the instruction is an alias of `ADD Rd, Rn, #0`.  Rn is encoded in bits 5-9 of the instruction and Rd in bits 0-4.  If either of those fields is set to `11111` then the corresponding operand is taken to be the stack pointer.  So if you set bits 5-9 to `11111` and bits 0-4 to `00000` then it does `ADD X0, SP, #0` or in other words `MOV X0, SP`.  If you set bits 5-9 to `00000` and bits 0-4 to `11111` then it does `ADD SP, X0, #0`, i.e. `MOV SP, X0`.

Comment: You could even set bits 5-9 and bits 0-4 both to `11111`, in which case you have `ADD SP, SP, #0` or in other words `MOV SP, SP`, a rather silly no-op.

Comment: Ohhh so it's one register but the position it's in determines direction, right??

Comment: Like you can put a register in Rd to make the stack pointer the destination or put it in Rn to make the stack pointer the source.  I'm not sure the specifics.  You'd think they would put this in the manual

Comment: I suppose you could think about it that way.  I would prefer to think about it in terms of this being a special case of a more general instruction that can take any register `Rn`, add an immediate constant `imm12`, and put the result in `Rd`.  When the constant is 0, it functions as a `MOV`, and so `MOV` is permitted as an alias mnemonic for the convenience of the programmer.  [...]

Comment: Also, it's a general principle of the architecture that for instructions that accept the stack pointer as an operand, as indicated by an `SP` in their mnemonic description, you select it with `11111` in the corresponding register field, as if the stack pointer were the (nonexistent) register `X31`.  (Most other instructions treat `11111` as the zero register `XZR`.)  So I would say that in this instruction, the source and destination are distinguished by the source being specified by `Rn` (bits 5-9) and the destination by `Rd` (bits 0-4).

Comment: And as mentioned, either or both of them can be the stack pointer.

Comment: But, if you really want to think of this as its own instruction and completely ignore its relationship to `ADD`, then yes, whether the non-SP register is the source or the destination is determined by whether you encode it in `Rn` or `Rd`, and you put `11111` in the other field.  However, if you want to understand the ARM64 encoding scheme, then IMHO it is much more helpful in the long run to focus on the more general instructions like `ADD` and realize that the aliases like `MOV` are just convenient shorthand for special cases.